# What does this error mean, and what is causing it?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

When using PHPMailer to send emails, I'm encountering a CN error with the message "ErrorException (E_WARNING) stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`sinaisdeforex.com' did not match expected CN." What does this error mean, and what is causing it? How can I resolve the error and successfully send email using PHPMailer? Are there any specific configuration changes or certificate updates that I need to make to ensure that the correct CN is being used when connecting to the email server?

I have a problem with PHPMaile and SMTPMailer on my LARAVEL site to use Amazon SES SMTP email provider. Try to resolve or troubleshoot credential deletion and create a new method-paid credential rather than resolution. Contact Amazon Support and I was informed: the upload request is failing validation on the PHP side. When you enter my site https://sinaisdeforex.com/contact-us click the button: SEND MESSAGE is reported or error:

```html
ErrorException (E_WARNING)
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`sinaisdeforex.com' did not match expected CN=`email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure).

You have the `Host` property in PHPMailer set to `sinaisdeforex.com`, but the mail server you are connecting to is not responding with a certificate that matches that name, so it's presumably an alias. Fix this by changing the name of the `Host` you're connecting to to one which matches the certificate, such as `email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: Where can I make this change?                                                                 
<b> APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_INSTALL=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost/softwarezon_signal_mod5

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306


SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null


PURCHASE_CODE=SOFTWAREZON_DEFAULT_CODE
BUYER_USERNAME=softwarezon </b>

Comment: At a guess, change `MAIL_HOST`

Comment: It is configured, check the link: https://ibb.co/C7Fm9Bs

Comment: All smtp configuration is inside softwarezon application 
in the member area of ​​my admin site

Comment: Will this issue only be resolved by the programmer who created the softwarezon application? Does the programmer need to make changes there?